# Can't get HttpPostedFileBase to bind correctly in Asp.Net MVC 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I can't have asp.net mvc 1.0 to bind HttpPostedFileBase for me.

this is my EditModel class.

```
public class PageFileEditModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my edit method header.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formCollection, PageFileEditModel[] pageFiles)
```

and this is my HTML

```
<input type="file" name="pageFiles[0].File" />
<input type="text" name="pageFiles[0].Category" />
<input type="file" name="pageFiles[1].File" />
<input type="text" name="pageFiles[1].Category" />
```

Category is bind correctly, but File is always null.

I've verifed that the files indeed are in `Request.Files`.

The `HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder` is added by default so can't figure out what is going wrong..

Comment: Only thing I can think of off the top of my head: Is the "enctype" attribute of your form set to "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: yes, I've verifed that the files indeed are in Request.Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in MVC 1 (fixed in MVC 2 RC) where HttpPostedFileBase objects aren't bound if they're properties on your model type rather than parameters to your action method.  Workaround for MVC 1:

```
<input type="file" name="theFile[0]" />
<input type="hidden" name="theFile[0].exists" value="true" />
<input type="file" name="theFile[1]" />
<input type="hidden" name="theFile[1].exists" value="true" />
```

That is, for each file upload element *foo* have a *foo*.exists hidden input element.  This will cause the DefaultModelBinder's short-circuiting logic not to kick in and it should correctly bind the HPFB property.

Comment: bam! to be exakt: <input type="file" name="pageFiles[0].File" />
<input type="hidden" name="pageFiles[0].File.exists" value="true" />

Answer (score 1):

This is a specification.

[Scott Hanselman's Computer Zen - ASP.NET MVC Beta released - Coolness Ensues](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCBetaReleasedCoolnessEnsues.aspx)

This is V1 RTW base model binder sample code.

1.Make custom model binder.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web
{
  public class HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder : IModelBinder
  {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      var bind = new PostedFileModel();
      var bindKey = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingContext.ModelName) ?
        "" : bindingContext.ModelName + ".") + "PostedFile";
      bind.PostedFile = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Files[bindKey];

      return bind;
    }
  }
}
```

2.Create model class.

```
using System.Web;

namespace Web
{
  public class PostedFileModel
  {
    public HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile { get; set; }
  }
}
```

3.Entry model binder in global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(PostedFileModel)] = 
                 new HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder();
}
```

Comment: I think unbinding HttpPostedFileBase on complex type.